# Horizontal Scrolling in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have a list of content which i want to display in a bootstrap grid of span9 and it has to scroll across only in the x axis. below you can find a snap shot of the design.

[image]

But i am not able to get it to work with

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

Link: http://play.mink7.com/mybooks/template.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content is not overflowing on the X axis because it just goes to a new line. You'd probably need to force the content to stay on one line with:

```
.featured-category ul {
    white-space: nowrap;    // add
}

.featured-category ul li {
    display: inline-block;  // add
    /*float: left;*/        // remove
}
```

Comment: I was just going just to suggest the inline-block addition ... but you edited the answer quicker, so all I can do now is give you a +1 ;-) Good job! ^_^

Comment: @MartinTurjak thanks for the +1, I initially formulated my answer just from the top of my head thinking what might be the issue, after reading the question. Then I followed the link provided to check my solution. Clearly only "nowrap" wasn't enough and I figured that "inline-block" was required as well. Your suggestion would have been correct.